# Combining specific rows that have NaN for a different column on python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am hoping this question makes sense.
I have a table I extracted from a PDF of chemical names that I am trying to format and I am having issues it looks like this: [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6F14.png)

Some of the chemical names are split into multiple rows and I need each name in its won row. I did notice the chemicals whose names are split into multiple rows have an NaN in the first column.

EDIT: after running
dt.head(15).to_dict()

{'Unnamed: 0': {6: '1',
7: nan,
8: '2',
9: '3',
10: nan,
11: nan,
12: '4',
13: '5',
14: nan,
15: nan,
16: '6',
17: '7',
18: '8',
19: '9',
20: nan},
'Phenolics': {6: 'Dihydroquercetin',
7: '7,30-dimethyl ether',
8: 'Artelin',
9: 'Esculin 7-',
10: 'methylether',
11: '(methylesculin)',
12: 'Esculin',
13: 'Scopoletin (7-',
14: 'hydroxy-6-',
15: 'methoxycoumarin)',
16: 'Axillarin',
17: 'Esculetin',
18: 'Isoscopoletin',
19: '6-Beta-D-glucosyl-7-',
20: 'methoxycoumarin'}}

Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: please run `df.head(15).to_dict()` and copy and paste the output there (edit post)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I edited the post to show the output

Comment: As far as I can see, the post only shows `df.head(15).to_dict()`, i.e. the first 15 rows of you dataframe. This reflects what's shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A one-line solution

```
df = df.fillna(method='ffill').groupby('Unnamed: 0')['Phenolics'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

Comment: This did work thanks! by any chance is there a way to apply this to my entire list?

Comment: Great, indeed. If you apply it to your entire `df` rather than only to `df.head(15)`. At least that's what I think you mean looking at the question and the suitable you provided.

Comment: it is more a copy then one-line

Comment: That was my bad I forgot I had done that. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, `df.head` produces another `pd.Dataframe`-instance from the original `df`. So it can be easy to accidentally truncate the data table via `df=df.head(15)`. Glad it worked.